# Will touchesBegan method called without UIView or UIViewController in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard, touchesbegan, resignfirstresponder

I created an app in where i have appdelegate class only. I dont create a UIView or a view controller. I just added textFields, labels and buttons in my window.

I want to hide the keyboard when the user taps out of the text boxes. This is normally achieved by the method touchesBegan. For implementing this method, two things we need to do.

One is add  in the header file(.h)

Another one is set the textField's delegate. Thats is, textField.delegate=self;

I did those two things. But still the touchesBegan method did not called.

Why? Should i have a UIView or UIViewController class for it?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

touchesBegan is a UIView method. if you want to do it in your setup you should create a UIView subclass, put all your controls in that one and implement touchesBegan in the UIView subclass.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... so, we can't use touchedBegan method without creating a UIView subclass?

Answer (score 3):

`UIWindow` is a subclass of `UIView`, so you could just hook into those. But this is a seriously bad design pattern. Consider modifying your application so it uses a single view controller, rather than doing everything in the app delegate. Otherwise you're jury-rigging the app delegate to be something it was never designed to do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... I know this is the bad. I just want to know why it is not working. So what i need to do to make it work with this situatuion?